# Data encrypted with openssl_public_encrypt is different every time?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa

why is the content of $encrypted every time different?

```
// aquire public key from server
$server_public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents("C:\publickey.pem"));

// rsa encrypt
openssl_public_encrypt("123", $encrypted, $server_public_key);
```

---

also I have tried this one

```
$publicKey = "file://C:/publickey.pem";
$privateKey = "file://C:/privatekey.pem";
$plaintext = "String to encrypt";

openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, $publicKey);
$transfer = base64_encode($encrypted);
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privateKey);

echo $transfer;  //encrypted string
```

and $transfer is everytime a different string:...

Z1xyMUquARxcGjqjjSHNAm41CnHI02GXxLyFivvta8YhDkhRJdD4i3kx+8GElljdiSY/NMF9UD3ritWMLGmscdq/QyIf+geYxJFePNd1dNWg+V6zbAKRLaEpsU+aB87jiM/GjytLEkI63dku02BS0ZBgz9UZw/FDNaynV5bTTDM=

mRgLPsPtMoV9la7zzuU+cLzS5xMDp7QUmH6Iv4Sv4/FNjt62zcv9ZMWkfG3uVhS8Z1UDtGl+met1CYjBTcfjHCR6hahbwOkTCICXtkRQcc371vURW04XhQzMNgIIbvN5BBdmIyYI6alrS2vKUq7b3T0h8sJf36zh5CynYzyDCFU=

G5FhMoJGiUwEBvEOeZpDDrEXdxbWX5iaJ6F+VdYJ3CURPRMftskZNlDhat8gA5V0G+3nXVQZptkHjxMkOqPlmwJHjgIqAiFppHLpEKohyT9qNwkAR00Y6PiWrNUJPiEIZqXHAb8TS0AA0Quhc0UAwcc+I8NGOD59k8BrZE6Z5Ew=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PKCS#1 encryption algorithm uses some random seed to make the cipher-text different every  time.

This protects the cipher-text against several attacks, like frequency analysis, ciphertext matching. For example, if you were using a public key to encrypt all your password without randomness. All the same password will yield the same cipher-text. Someone can figure out all the popular passwords by checking the frequency of the cipher-text.

For symmetric key encryption, IV (Initial Vector) serves a similar purpose.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the random seed and sent it to another pkcs#1 encryption algorithm which will use it to decrypt some data encrypted from the first pkcs#1 algorithm?

Comment: @panny: please read the PKCS#1 specification. You don't need to do what your asking, the PKCS#1 format makes it possible to remove the random bits by the decryptor without knowing them in advance. Your rsa decryption function almost certainly does this for you.

Comment: Symmetric key encryption doesn't have the same problem (of ciphertext matching), since with a symmetric algorithm anyone who can generate ciphertext for a candidate plaintext must already have the key.