# openssl_public_encrypt returning different values for same input in php

Tags: php

I have an email address stored as encrypted strings in my database,

I have a situation where the user enters their email address, and I have to find if it matches the corresponding email in my database.

So I encrypt their input and then compare it to the value stored in my database.

However, when I encrypt their input, even if they have the correct email address, the encrypted input value is different from the one I have encrypted and stored previously.

The code to encrypt is

```
 openssl_public_encrypt($input,$encrypted,$key);
```

Seems each time I call this function, even if I have the same inputs it returns a different encrypted value.

Is there a way I can prevent generating a different encrypted value each time?

Thanks

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979994/data-encrypted-with-openssl-public-encrypt-is-different-every-time

Comment: You need to re-evaluate why you think you need to encrypt this information at all, and then not do that.